# How to use a (while) loop and where to place it if eligible for all code

Tags: c++, while-loop

On c++, im trying to make a program that will repeatedly accept the input of the user unless -999 is pressed. Additionally, if the input is not divisible by 5 or 20, then I asked for it to output "must enter divisible by 5 or 20." I want this to continue being done until they enter -999 but I do not know where to put my while loop or what to put if it is not entered. I also do not know where to put the "when finished enter -999 to leave" while making it eligible for all times and not just the start. Thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int amountEntered;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of money you would like to dispense (must be in 20's or 5's)" << endl;
    cout << "when finished, enter -999 to leave" << endl;
    if (amountEntered == -999)
    {
        cout << "Thank you for doing business." << endl;
    }

    cin >> amountEntered;

    if (amountEntered % 20 == 0)
    {
        cout << amountEntered / 20 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (amountEntered % 5 == 0)
        {
            cout << amountEntered / 5 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You must enter multiples of twenty or five only!" << endl;
        }
    }
    {
        while (amountEntered != -999);
        while (amountEntered % 5 == 0);
    else
    {
        if (amountEntered % 5 != 0)
        {
            cout << "You must enter multiples of twenty or five only!" << endl;
        }
    }

    while (amountEntered % 20 == 0);
    }
    if (amountEntered % 20 != 0);
    {
        cout << "You must enter a number divisible by 20 or 5!" << endl;
    }

    if (amountEntered = -999)
    {
        cout << "Thank you for doing business." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have some quite interesting `while`-loops in your code. And an `else` without a matching `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
while true
    get input
        if input is -999 (or other conditions)
            break out of loop
        else
            // rest of code goes here
```

So basically, wrap the whole thing in a `while true` loop and then use the conditional logic to break out of the loop when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Too complicated.

Comment: @Swordfish How is this "complicated"?!

Comment: I kind of like it

Comment: Not overly complicated, just high-level. More pedagogically beneficial to explicate a pattern that can be used in other scenarios, rather than a rewrite of their code."Teach a man to fish and he eats for a lifetime"

Answer (score 1):

> On c++, im trying to make a program that will repeatedly accept the input of the user unless - 999 is pressed.
>   Additionally, if the input is not divisible by 5 or 20, then I asked for it to output "must enter divisible by 5 or 20."

```
#include <limits>    // std::numeric_limits<>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (;;) {  // forever
        int value;
        while (std::cout << "Thou must enter a value divisible by 5 or 20. When finished enter -999 to leave.\n",
               !(std::cin >> value) || value != -999 && value % 5 != 0 && value % 20 != 0)
        //     ^^ extraction failed or value does not conform to requirements
        {
            std::cerr << "Input error :(\nYou must enter a number divisible by 5 or 20.\n";
            std::cin.clear();  // clear the flags that might have been set by a 
                               // failed input operation.
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            // ^^ discards up to the maximum value of std::streamsize characters
            //    until a newline character ('\n') is encountered. If we don't do that
            //    the next input operation will choke on the same erroneous input.
        }

        if (value == -999)
            break;

        // do sth with value
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not do what was asked, and the part that does is functionally-equivalent to but more complicated than the other solution already posted that you rejected as "too complicated" lol

Comment: Oh and you dropped the `-` from `-999` for some reason

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Look again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Does what is asked now.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Care to elaborate?

Comment: Care to read the question? Pay careful attention to the part about how the user prompts/output is supposed to act.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Better?

Comment: *Care to read the question?* – I feel intrigued to flag that. It is obvious that i did read the question.

Comment: Just gave an upvote because I am also very sure that it does exactly what the OP asked for

Comment: The answer is now approaching something resembling what was asked for.

Comment: I feel like it is not that obvious that you read the question when you got two key details of it wrong. Feel free to flag away though. Good night!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *grrrr* Stop talking in riddles. Which "two key details" are wrong!?

Comment: I told you what they are already. You got the output semantics wrong, and you got the termination value wrong. Those are not "meaningless details", they are 80% of the question's requirements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are referring to an old version of this answer.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes, I am, because after I pointed out those problems, you fixed them, and I have already said that it is better now as a result. Not sure why we're still talking about it? Move on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am still talking about it because you still claim that something is wrong with my code and it doesn't match the OPs requirements. ("On c++, im trying to make a program that will repeatedly accept the input of the user unless -999 is pressed. Additionally, if the input is not divisible by 5 or 20, then I asked for it to output "must enter divisible by 5 or 20." I want this to continue being done until they enter -999") Not to mention that the request in the question is FUBAR in itself when interpreter is being picky.

Comment: @Swordfish No, I do not still claim that. You seem to simply be looking for an argument. Me = done here!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That seems to be some sort of misunderstanding. I am not looking for an argument. My understanding was that you kept saying that my code doesn't fullfill the requirements. (I've got to do better things as well. Sleep as a start ...)

Answer (score 0):

> I want this to continue being done until they enter -999 but I do not know where to put my while loop or what to put if it is not entered. I also do not know where to put the "when finished enter -999 to leave" while making it eligible for all times and not just the start.

Perhaps you might want to break the problem down. Firstly, you would know that the "end condition" of this loop would be that the user keyed in -999. Hence you would want your loop to look something like

```
while userinput != -999
    // do something here
end while loop
```

With that, all we need is to place the capturing of user input. One would be at the start, and one just before the while loop ends.

```
get userinput
while userinput != -999
    // do something here
    get userinput
end while loop
```

There are several ways to approach this problem, and that's depending on how you want to design your code. Here's my approach for this:

```
#include <iostream>

void Request(int& amount)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of money you would like to dispense (must be in 20's or 5's)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "when finished, enter -999 to leave" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ">";
    std::cin >> amount;
}

int main(void)
{
    int amount = 0;

    for (Request(amount); amount != -999; Request(amount))
    {
        // Since 20 is a multiple of 5, just check if its divisble by 5 will do 
        if (amount % 5)
        {
            std::cout << "You must enter multiples of twenty or five only!" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        // Otherwise print out (or do stuff here)
        std::cout << amount % 5 << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Thank you for doing business." << std::endl;
}
```